# Is Nonblocking IO in Project Reactor really nonblocking?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, nonblocking

I have created the diagram below. I am just not able to understand that how threads are not blocked in case of Spring Webflux/Project Reactor.

In the below image, request came to my Netty server and one of the threads (reactor-http-nio-1) was assigned to the request, it passed on the flow and then became available for next work.

After sometime, response came and was assigned to Thread2 (reactor-http-nio-2). It was returned to the client.

But there has to be something, right, which should wait for the response, (or be in blocking state), or something that wakes up when response is received and it knows it have to assign a thread to the response and then thread returns response to their respective client who made that request, to prevent interleaving.

Is my understanding correct that blocking is still involved, but we have just offloaded the process of blocking to some other thread (internal maybe). Or is the system made capable enough to go in dormant state after passing on the request and waking back up only when response arrives. If latter is the case, how does this mechanism work?

This question may be too broad, but some resource or explanation will be really helpful for clarification.

[image]

Comment: This is taken care of at the operating system level. There does not need to be a Java thread that's waiting for the response. Take a look at this article: [How does non-blocking IO work under the hood?](https://medium.com/ing-blog/how-does-non-blocking-io-work-under-the-hood-6299d2953c74)

Comment: Seems like at OS level, there is a mapping, which knows that after reading data from the sockets/file descriptors, how the data will be sent to the correct client to prevent interleaving. However there is still a live connection from the client waiting for that response to be delivered, its just that no resources are getting consumed on the server for that active connection (or waiting connection, please correct this if this parenthesis's  assumption is wrong) @Jesper

Comment: Yes, there is a live connection, but that doesn't mean that there has to be a thread running (whether it's at the Java level or the OS level) that is waiting for the response. The OS keeps a list of open connections, and if data is received it looks up where that data belongs, and then it activates a thread to handle it.

Comment: There is `Selector.select()`. Inside Netty. Not your concern.