# Reactive Stack, understanding needed around the internals

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

This is in continuation to a [question asked by me 7 months back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71824405/is-nonblocking-io-in-project-reactor-really-nonblocking) to understand the reactive programming, because I haven't seen any articles which explain the concepts around this other than the use of operators in depth, I feel my knowledge is shallow around this, hence asking what my assumptions are, what I am unclear about, and what I know of the era used before the reactive programming.

I understand that Java before having reactive support used to work like below,
If we need to fetch some results from database,

1. Client made and http request
2. Server received it and assigned a thread from the pool.
3. Database driver interacted with the database, in blocking manner
4. Database server returned results to the thread.
5. The waiting thread returned the results to the client and is now freed.

Please see the below image, depicting the same, and correct me If I am wrong anywhere

[image]

Now What I know/learned/understand of reactive is,

For a system to be completely reactive, "Every component in the lifecycle of a process (for ex HTTP request to fetch some results) must be reactive."

So I assume from the above statement that below things must have been happening in reactive stack.

[image]

Is this a correct understanding?

If yes, then how R2DBC, is making it possible to develop applications with non reactive databases, Is it mimicking only?

Comment: R2BDC is just the driver, the client. The entire database isnt reactive.

Comment: ok, so the dbs' which support reactive, do they have their drivers only reactive or the db as well(lets forget r2dbc)

Comment: dbs? i have no idea what you are talking about. A database, mysql, mongo, neo4j all have an api. To communicate with the database, you use a driver which is embedded into a client. Java has written a specification what such a driver should look like. Most common one is JDBC that follows the JDBC specification. The JDBC specc is written inherently blocking because of transactions (read the spec). so there was a need for a new spec R2DBC which is not inherently blocking. The database has no idea if your application is reactive or not.

Comment: the entire reactive concept actually depends on event loops. so while the app is waiting for the answer of an io operation, it can schedule new task on the given thread. for example, the app goes to the db through r2dbc, then it immediately returns with a future value (Mono/Flux in webflux terminology), the underlaying system put it into a queue and event loop monitoring this. when the value(s) arrive, eventloop schedule it on a thread. As you may see reactive types act like a callback, and db does not have to know anything about the app. The only important aspect is the driver has to return

Comment: with reactive type. If you interested in the concept, there are many books about reactive systems, event loop, java nio and also netty.

Comment: @zlaval Thanks for the explanation,  As I have mentioned in my question, I was thinking may be the DB servers are made that capable as well, that they can prepare data from a query in chunks, (for example if some query returns 100 records then DB server will stream data not fully, but one by one, as soon as the first records ready, which seems illogical) which is not the case according to your comment. Alright, hence the reactivity is only on the level of APP server basically, not any where else.  Am I correct? Pardon me, if I am not making sense, just was  unable to wrap my head around this.

Comment: this is where it starts to become more complex. this depends on how the underlaying db materialize the result. it might send a row immediatelly when the query findd it, or the whole result. also you can use cursor, there are backpressure support and so on.
i suggest you read the documentation of r2dbc spec and also the db u are using.